# Riverpod StreamProvider Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments

Tags: flutter, provider, stream-builder, riverpod

I am learning flutter and have just updated app to include Riverpods. I have a collection within a collection and so need to pass two parameters. One is called localAuthId and the other is called orgId.

When I setup the Streambuilder I get an error saying there are too many positional arguments.

Here is the snippet that seems to be causing the problem

```
**final orgStreamProvider =
StreamProvider.autoDispose.family<Org, String>((ref, localAuthId, orgId) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database != null && localAuthId != null && orgId !=null
      ? database.orgDocStream(localAuthId: localAuthId, orgId: orgId)
      : const Stream.empty();
})**
```

When I run the following on the top level collection i.e. with just 1 parameter of localAuthId it works just fine.

```
**final orgStreamProvider =
StreamProvider.autoDispose.family<Org, String>((ref, localAuthId) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database != null && localAuthId != null
      ? database.orgDocStream(localAuthId: localAuthId)
      : const Stream.empty();
});**
```

Does anyone know what I am getting wrong with this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As of now, You can pass only one value to the provider using [family](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/all/StreamProviderFamily-class.html) of Riverpod. Better create one class with two properties and pass the object to the provider.

```
class Auth {
  Auth({
    @required this.localAuthId,
    @required this.orgId,
  });
  final String localAuthId;
  final String orgId;
}

final auth = Auth(localAuthId: 'abc', orgId: 'abc1234');

final orgStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose.family<Org, Auth>((ref, auth) {
  final database = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
  return database != null && auth.localAuthId != null && auth.orgId !=null
    ? database.orgDocStream(localAuthId: auth.localAuthId, orgId: auth.orgId)
    : const Stream.empty();
})
```

With `hooks_riverpod`

```
final orgProvider = useProvider(orgStreamProvider(auth));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this. I tried this but still couldn't manage to get this to work, unfortunately, so I went with another method. Appreciate your help